# Ordering a DataFrame by a bigger group (R)

Tags: r, sorting, dplyr

I want to sort a dataframe by a 'sum' of a group. So, I don't want the data frame to be ordered by group, but by the total amount of a group. I.e. I want to know which group is the biggest, 1 or 2 or 3 and then order the values according to that. So, say group 3 is the biggest group, then I want group 3 at the top and I want the values of group 3 in descending order.

```
set.seed(123)
d <- data.frame(
  x   = runif(90),
  grp = gl(3, 30))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One way using `dplyr` is

```
d %>% 
  group_by(grp) %>% 
  mutate(sum_ = sum(x)) %>% 
  arrange(desc(sum_), desc(x)) %>% 
  select(-sum_)
```

Basically, we create a temporary variable `sum_` that indicates the sum of `x` by group, and then arrange according to `sum_` first and `x` second. Afterwards, we remove `sum_` since it's no longer needed.

Output

```
# A tibble: 90 x 2
# Groups:   grp [3]
#        x grp  
#    <dbl> <fct>
#  1 0.994 1    
#  2 0.957 1    
#  3 0.955 1    
#  4 0.940 1    
#  5 0.900 1    
#  6 0.892 1    
#  7 0.890 1    
#  8 0.883 1    
#  9 0.788 1    
# 10 0.709 1    
# ... with 80 more rows
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to reorder the levels of `grp` according to the sum of `x`. This can be done with `tidyverse` like this:

```r
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(123)

df <- tibble(
  x   = runif(90),
  grp = gl(3, 30)
)

df %>% 
  mutate(
    grp = fct_reorder(grp, x, .fun = "sum", .desc = TRUE)
  ) %>% 
  arrange(grp)
#> # A tibble: 90 x 2
#>         x grp  
#>     <dbl> <fct>
#>  1 0.288  1    
#>  2 0.788  1    
#>  3 0.409  1    
#>  4 0.883  1    
#>  5 0.940  1    
#>  6 0.0456 1    
#>  7 0.528  1    
#>  8 0.892  1    
#>  9 0.551  1    
#> 10 0.457  1    
#> # … with 80 more rows


df %>% 
  group_by(grp) %>% 
  summarise(tot = sum(x))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>   grp     tot
#>   <fct> <dbl>
#> 1 1      17.2
#> 2 2      13.2
#> 3 3      15.4
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

In *base* you can first use `order` on all, than split by *grp* and `rbind` by the `order` of `rowsum`.

```
d <- d[order(-d$x),]
do.call(rbind, split(d, d$grp)[order(-rowsum(d$x, d$grp))])
#                x grp
#1.24 0.9942697766   1
#1.11 0.9568333453   1
#1.20 0.9545036491   1
#1.5  0.9404672843   1
#1.16 0.8998249704   1
#1.8  0.8924190444   1
#1.21 0.8895393161   1
#1.4  0.8830174040   1
#1.2  0.7883051354   1
#1.26 0.7085304682   1
#1.22 0.6928034062   1
#1.13 0.6775706355   1
#1.25 0.6557057991   1
#1.23 0.6405068138   1
#1.28 0.5941420204   1
#1.14 0.5726334020   1
#1.9  0.5514350145   1
#1.27 0.5440660247   1
#1.7  0.5281054880   1
#1.10 0.4566147353   1
#1.12 0.4533341562   1
#1.3  0.4089769218   1
#1.19 0.3279207193   1
#1.29 0.2891597373   1
#1.1  0.2875775201   1
#1.17 0.2460877344   1
#1.30 0.1471136473   1
#1.15 0.1029246827   1
#1.6  0.0455564994   1
#1.18 0.0420595335   1
#3.87 0.9849569800   3
#3.88 0.8930511144   3
#3.89 0.8864690608   3
#3.65 0.8146400389   3
#3.68 0.8123895095   3
#3.67 0.8100643530   3
#3.69 0.7943423211   3
#3.84 0.7881958340   3
#3.71 0.7544751586   3
#3.73 0.7101824014   3
#3.82 0.6680555874   3
#3.61 0.6651151946   3
#3.72 0.6292211316   3
#3.78 0.6127710033   3
#3.75 0.4753165741   3
#3.66 0.4485163414   3
#3.70 0.4398316876   3
#3.86 0.4348927415   3
#3.83 0.4176467797   3
#3.63 0.3839696378   3
#3.77 0.3798165377   3
#3.79 0.3517979092   3
#3.64 0.2743836446   3
#3.81 0.2436194727   3
#3.76 0.2201188852   3
#3.90 0.1750526503   3
#3.80 0.1111354243   3
#3.85 0.1028646443   3
#3.62 0.0948406609   3
#3.74 0.0006247733   3
#2.31 0.9630242325   2
#2.32 0.9022990451   2
#2.59 0.8950453592   2
#2.50 0.8578277153   2
#2.53 0.7989248456   2
#2.34 0.7954674177   2
#2.37 0.7584595375   2
#2.58 0.7533078643   2
#2.33 0.6907052784   2
#2.55 0.5609479838   2
#2.36 0.4777959711   2
#2.48 0.4659624503   2
#2.52 0.4422000742   2
#2.42 0.4145463358   2
#2.43 0.4137243263   2
#2.60 0.3744627759   2
#2.44 0.3688454509   2
#2.39 0.3181810076   2
#2.49 0.2659726404   2
#2.47 0.2330340995   2
#2.40 0.2316257854   2
#2.38 0.2164079358   2
#2.56 0.2065313896   2
#2.45 0.1524447477   2
#2.41 0.1428000224   2
#2.46 0.1388060634   2
#2.57 0.1275316502   2
#2.54 0.1218992600   2
#2.51 0.0458311667   2
#2.35 0.0246136845   2
```

Another option is to reorder the `levels` of *grp* which can than be used in `order`.

```
d$grp <- factor(d$grp, levels(d$grp)[order(-rowsum(d$x, d$grp))])
d[order(d$grp, -d$x),]
```